# Error in unikn::usecol(pal = pal_pinky, n = 12): object 'pal_pinky' not found

Tags: r

I'm facing an error in R. It's just started occurring due to a change I must have inadvertently made. The issue is that it runs fine on my desktop machine. But fails when running in a docker image in the cloud.

```
options(TEMP_COLOURS = unikn::usecol(pal = pal_pinky, n = 5))
options(HUM_COLOURS = unikn::usecol(pal = pal_seeblau, n = 5))
```

Gives the error: `Error in unikn::usecol(pal = pal_pinky, n = 5): object 'pal_pinky' not found`. I've added in

```
library(unikn)
```

to make sure the library is installed and available. Sorry it's not much to go on. Any R experts out there who can decipher this error or suggest a mechanism to capture the cause?

Comment: How about `options(TEMP_COLOURS = unikn::usecol(pal = unikn::pal_pinky, n = 5))`

Comment: @DarrenTsai I'll give it a whirl. Takes a while to rebuild the docker image though.